# Weights in MySql

Tags: mysql

Basically what I need to achieve is a table in which users insert different food products. So obviously I need to allow people to specify weights (1000g, 23oz or what ever). How should I go about doing this? Do I create a look-up table with the values of an oz, lb, kg all in Grams?

I need to be able to use these values in recipes. The procedure will go along the lines of this:

User enters Products (with weights & prices), User uses products from his/her inventory to create recipes, then show the cost for each recipe. So say someone puts "Butter, 250g and costs £0.99" then writes a recipe which requires 500g of butter the calculator will work out the cost of the recipe. Which is all easy enough, it's when people then want to use LB, Oz, Cups blah blah as different measurements.

Comment: This has been done before. Do some research.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The records containing the measurements don't need to know or care about the *type* of measurement they store.  Just the *value*.  It could be something as simple as this:

```
Ingredients
----------
ID
Name

MeasurementTypes
----------
ID
Name

Measurements
----------
ID
IngredientID
MeasurementTypeID
RecipeID
Amount
Description

Recipes
----------
ID
Name
Description
```

In the above design, Ingredients are things like flour, sugar, eggs, etc.  Measurement Types are things like cups, ounces, count, etc.  Recipes are the main recipes themselves with titles and descriptions.  And Measurements are a many-to-one child of Recipes which link them to their Ingredients.  So a sample record might be:

```
Recipes
----------
1    Ramen Noodle Soup    Boil water, add noodles, stir, eat.

Ingredients
----------
1    Instant Ramen Noodle Soup
2    Water

MeasurementTypes
----------
1    Packages
2    Cups

Measurements
----------
1    1    1    1    1    Use one package of instant Ramen Noodle Soup.
2    2    2    1    2    Use two cups of water.
```

Answer (score 1):

*Always* store your measurements using a single set of units.

Everything else then becomes a *presentation* problem.